# evalf and subs in sympy on single variable expression returns expression instead of expected float value

Tags: python, sympy

I'm new to sympy and I'm trying to use it to get the values of higher order Greeks of options (basically higher order derivatives). My goal is to do a Taylor series expansion. The function in question is the first derivative.

f(x) = N(d1)

N(d1) is the P(X <= d1) of a standard normal distribution. d1 in turn is another function of x (x in this case is the price of the stock to anybody who's interested).

```
d1 = (np.log(x/100) + (0.01 + 0.5*0.11**2)*0.5)/(0.11*np.sqrt(0.5))
```

As you can see, d1 is a function of only x. This is what I have tried so far.

```
import sympy as sp
from math import pi
from sympy.stats import Normal,P

x = sp.symbols('x')
u = (sp.log(x/100) + (0.01 + 0.5*0.11**2)*0.5)/(0.11*np.sqrt(0.5))
N = Normal('N',0,1)
f = sp.simplify(P(N <= u))
print(f.evalf(subs={x:100})) # This should be 0.5155
f1 = sp.simplify(sp.diff(f,x))
f1.evalf(subs={x:100}) # This should also return a float value
```

The last line of code however returns an expression, not a float value as I expected like in the case with f. I feel like I'm making a very simple mistake but I can't find out why. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is just a bug in sympy's evalf routine. It would be better to report it: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: Also, last line has a syntax error

Comment: `f1` has some `polar_lift(x)` terms, which may prevent the `evalf`. (Just a guess).

Comment: `diff(polar_lift(x)).evalf(subs={x:100})` does not return a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `x` with `positive=True` (which is implied by the `log` in the definition of `u` assuming `u` is real which is implied by the definition of `f`) it looks like you get almost the expected result (also using `f1.subs({x:100})` in the version without the positive `x` assumption shows the trouble is with unevaluated `polar_lift(0)` terms):

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.stats import Normal, P

x = sp.symbols('x', positive=True)
u = (sp.log(x/100) + (0.01 + 0.5*0.11**2)*0.5)/(0.11*sp.sqrt(0.5)) # changed np to sp
N = Normal('N',0,1)
f = sp.simplify(P(N <= u))
print(f.evalf(subs={x:100})) # 0.541087287864516
f1 = sp.simplify(sp.diff(f,x))
print(f1.evalf(subs={x:100})) # 0.0510177033783834
```